# Difference between x = null vs. x IS NULL

Tags: sql, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-null

In Snowflake, what is the difference between `x = NULL` and `x IS NULL` in a condition expression? It seems empirically that `x IS NULL` is what I want when I want to find rows where some column is blank. I ask because `x = NULL` is treated as valid syntax and I am curious whether there's a different application for this expression.

Comment: `x = NULL` always returns `null`

Comment: `x = NULL` is valid, but the rub with `NULL` is that nothing is equal to it, not even `NULL`; so even `WHERE NULL = NULL` will fail, which is why we have `IS NULL` functionality for this special case.

Comment: Btw, in Snowflake you can can also do `where X is not distinct from Y` instead of  `where X=Y`,  to account for NULLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular case is well-described in Snowflake's documentation:

> [EQUAL_NULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null.html)
>
> [IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html)
>
> Compares whether two expressions are equal. **The function is NULL-safe, meaning it treats NULLs as known values for comparing equality. *Note that this is different from the EQUAL comparison operator (=), which treats NULLs as unknown values*.**

```
+------+------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| X1_I | X2_I | X1.I IS NOT DISTINCT FROM X2.I | SELECT IF X1.I IS NOT DISTINCT FROM X2.I | X1.I IS DISTINCT FROM X2.I | SELECT IF X1.I IS DISTINCT FROM X2.I |
|------+------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|    1 |    1 | True                           | Selected                                 | False                      | Not                                  |
|    1 |    2 | False                          | Not                                      | True                       | Selected                             |
|    1 | NULL | False                          | Not                                      | True                       | Selected                             |
|    2 |    1 | False                          | Not                                      | True                       | Selected                             |
|    2 |    2 | True                           | Selected                                 | False                      | Not                                  |
|    2 | NULL | False                          | Not                                      | True                       | Selected                             |
| NULL |    1 | False                          | Not                                      | True                       | Selected                             |
| NULL |    2 | False                          | Not                                      | True                       | Selected                             |
| NULL | NULL | True                           | Selected                                 | False                      | Not                                  |
+------+------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 6):

> what is the difference between x = NULL and x IS NULL

In Snowflake just like in other RDBMS, Nothing is equal to `NULL` (even `NULL` itself), so a condition `x = NULL` (which is valid SQL syntax) will always evaluate as false (well, actually, it evaluates to `NULL` in most RDBMS, which is not true). Note that this is also true for non-equality comparisons: that is `NULL <> NULL` is false too.

The typical way to check if a variable is `NULL` is to use the `x IS NULL` construct, which evaluate as true if `x` is `NULL`. You can use `x IS NOT NULL` too. This syntax is reserved for `NULL`, so something like `x IS y` is a syntax error.

Here is [a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dc8a28bce34543284b019fcdb8420fe):

```
select 
    case when 1 = null then 1 else 0 end 1_equal_null,
    case when 1 <> null then 1 else 0 end 1_not_equal_null,
    case when null is null then 1 else 0 end null_is_null,
    case when 1 is not null then 1 else 0 end 1_is_not_null
```

```
1_equal_null | 1_not_equal_null | null_is_null | 1_is_not_null
-----------: | ---------------: | -----------: | ------------:
           0 |                0 |            1 |             1
```

Answer (score 1):

Like most SQL languages, comparing `NULL = NULL` does not return `TRUE`. In SnowFlake, it returns `NULL`, as does ANY comparison to a `NULL` value. The reason for this is tied to the convoluted history of SQL, and it has been well argued whether or not this is a good feature or not. Regardless, it's what we have.

As such, when you are comparing two values that may be NULL here are a few different solutions you can typically use.

```
-- NVL will return the second value if the first value is NULL
-- So if both of your values are NULL, then an NVL around each of them will 
-- return a value so that they are both equal.
-- This only works if you know that your values will never be equal to -1 for example
SELECT ...
WHERE NVL(x, -1) = NVL(y, -1)

-- A little messier, especially among more complicated filters,
-- but guaranteed to work regardless of values
SELECT ...
WHERE x = y OR (x is null and y is null)

-- My new favorite which works in SnowFlake (thanks to @waldente)
SELECT x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y;

-- For most SQL languages, this is a neat way to take advantage of how 
-- INTERSECT compares values which does treat NULLs as equal
SELECT ...
WHERE exists (select x intersect select y)
```